# Targeting specific row/line of textarea and appending that row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to click on a specific element, and have it send a value to a textarea. However, I want it to append to a specific row/line of the textarea.

What I am trying to build is very similar to what happens when you click the notes of the fret board on this site: http://www.guitartabcreator.com/version2/ In fact, i want it almost exactly the same as this.

But right now I am really just trying to see how I can target the specific row, as it seems doable based on this website.

Currently I am using javascript to send a value based on clicking a specific element.

#### Here is the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function addNote0(text,element_id) {
document.getElementById(element_id).value += text;
}

</script>
```

#### This is the HTML that represents the clickable element:

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="addNote0('O','tabText'); return false;"> x </a></td>
```

#### This is the textarea:

```
<textarea rows="6" cols="24" id="tabText" name="text">-
-
-
-
-
-</textarea>
```

This works fine for sending the value. But it obviously just goes to the next available space. I am a total newb when it comes to javascript, so I am just not sure where to begin with trying to target a specific line.

What I have currently can be viewed here: http://aldentec.com/tab/

## Working code:

After some help, here is the final code that made this work:

```
<script>

function addNote0(text,element_id) {
document.getElementById(element_id).value += text;


var tabTextRows = ['','','','','',''];

$('td').click(function(){
  var fret = $(this).index() - 1;
  var line = $(this).parent().index() -1;
  updateNote(fret, line);
});

function updateNote(fret, line){
  var i;
  for(i=0;i<tabTextRows.length;i++){
    if(i == line) tabTextRows[i]+='-'+fret+'-';
    else tabTextRows[i]+='---';
    $('#tabText').val(tabTextRows.join('\n'));
  }
}}

window.onload = function() {
  addNote0('', 'tabText');
};

</script>
```

Comment: textareas use chars ranges instead of lines and cols. you have to convert between the two. ta.value.slice(0, ta.selectionStart).split("\n").length will tell you what "line" the cursor is on, while selectionStart tells you what char the cursor is at.

Comment: There are no “rows” in a textarea value per se – you’ll have to split it by newline characters if you want to determine rows by that (and maybe even take into account automatic wrapping), or use selections as dandavis already said. // _“I am a total newb when it comes to javascript”_ – so why does your portfolio on the same page say that you’re “proficient” in JS then …?

Comment: In the guitar tab example you gave, they're generating the entire textarea content each time you change anything.

Comment: @CBroe Well good point there. I guess I thought I was better with it than I am when that was written. I should probably remove that from my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to solve this only in JS.

What I did here is use an array to model each row of the textfield (note the array length is 6).

Then I used a jQuery selector to trigger any time a `<td>` element is clicked which calculates the fret and string that was clicked relative to the HTML tree then calls the updateNote function. (If you change the table, the solution will probably break).

In the update note function, I iterate through the tabTextRows array, adding the appropriate note. Finally, I set the value of the `<textarea>` to the array joined by '\n' (newline char).

Works for me on the site you linked.

This solution is dependant on jQuery however, so make sure that's included.

Also you should consider using a `monospaced font` so the spacing doesn't get messed up.

```
var tabTextRows = ['','','','','',''];

$('td').click(function(){
  var fret = $(this).index() - 1;
  var line = $(this).parent().index() -1;
  updateNote(fret, line);
});

function updateNote(fret, line){
  var i;
  for(i=0;i<tabTextRows.length;i++){
    if(i == line) tabTextRows[i]+='-'+fret+'-';
    else tabTextRows[i]+='---';
    $('#tabText').val(tabTextRows.join('\n'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the info with this! For some reason this is not working for me. Replaced my javascript code with this and made sure I included jQuery. Anything aside from that I should have to do?

Comment: when you had it working, did you just put that code in the header, replacing my existing js?

Comment: No, I just appended that code to what you already had, that worked for me.

Comment: Ok I got it working now. However it's a little odd. Basically I have to click the `<td><a href="#" onclick="addNote0('O','tabText'); return false;"> x </a></td>` first. Then I can click any `<td>` and it will work. But only after clicking the `<a href>` first. 

After that if I click the actually `<a href>` again, it clears everything out. Any thoughts?

Comment: Scratch that, got it working. thank you SOOOOO much for this. I will mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the [guitartabcreator](http://www.guitartabcreator.com) website.  Jacob Mattison is correct - I am using the text area for display purposes. Managing the data occurs in the backend.  After seeing your site, it looks like you've got the basics of my idea down.